# Programming with Apache::DBI and firebird. Get Stucked httpd on exception

Tags: perl, firebird, mod-perl

I have an issues on Web application programming with Firebird.

I'm using mod_perl and Apache::DBI with Firebird.
And also using `CGI::Session` for session handling.
`CGI::Session` uses an already connected `$dbh` with Firebird.

AutoCommit is ON.
Every(multiple) sql execution is wrapped by `eval {}` statement.
for example,

```
$dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Firebird:db=$DBSERVER:/home/cdbs/xxnet.fdb;
ib_charset=UTF8;ib_dialect=3",$DBUSER,$DBPASS,{
    AutoCommit=>1,
    LongReadLen=>8192,
    RaiseError=>1
});
eval { $dbh->begin_work()

  my $sql = "SELECT * FROM SAMPLETABLE"
  my $st = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $st->execute();
  while (my $R = $st->fetchrow_hashref()) {
   ...
  }
  $st->finish();
}; warn $@ if $@;
if ($@) {
  $dbh->rollback();
}else{
  $dbh->commit();
}
```

When an exception was raised in eval section, execute warn statement and try to rollback transaction.
Error messages are logged in error_log,after that, `$dbh` is going to get stuck -- CGI::Session returns no data.
I thought 'warn' statement includes 'rollback', so I tried to comment out `$dbh->rollback()` statement. It looks good.

Other ways, I use 'warn' to log debug message -- like `print STDERR $@`.
httpd is going to get stuck like as above.

With Oracle(DBD::Oracle), I didn't see these situation.

Please tell me which part is BAD for using transaction with firebird ?
warn ? DBD::Firebird ?

Thanks.

Yasuto,

Comment: `warn` is just a Perl built-in that sends a message to your STDOUT. It's used for printing warnings. It has nothing to do with your database, and it cannot do a rollback. Your code looks fine.

Comment: so,what do you mean? I'm looking for workaround s.

Comment: I got an answer of my issue.

$dbh was not broken after raise exceptions and catch them.

An another issue is 'cached statements are broken.'
I use CGI::Session with Driver::DBI to share connected handle.
prepare_cached() in the CGI::Session fails.

I don't know who accepts and maintain this issue....
Please help.