# Solved: DBI cached statements gone and CGI::Session is stucked

Tags: perl, session, firebird, dbi, mod-perl

I'm using Apache2.2(worker)/mod_perl 2.0.4/Apache::DBI/CGI::Session and Firebird RDBMS.

I also wrote CGI::Session::Driver::firebird.pm to work with Firebird RDBMS.
DB connection is pooled by Apache::DBI and give connection handle to CGI::Session {Handle=>$dbh}.

Number of DB connection is equals to number of worker processes.

I posted [Programming with Apache::DBI and firebird. Get Stucked httpd on exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42981824) 3 month ago.
I found a reason of that issue, and want to know how to fix it.

```
$dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Firebird:db=$DBSERVER:/home/cdbs/xxnet.fdb;
ib_charset=UTF8;ib_dialect=3",$DBUSER,$DBPASS,{
    AutoCommit=>1,
    LongReadLen=>8192,
    RaiseError=>1
});
my $session = new CGI::Session('dbi:firebird',$sessid,{Handle=>$dbh});
my $ses_p1 = $session->param('p1');

eval { $dbh->begin_work()

  my $sql = "SELECT * FROM SAMPLETABLE"
  my $st = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $st->execute();
  while (my $R = $st->fetchrow_hashref()) {
   ...
  }
  $st->finish();
}; warn $@ if $@;
if ($@) {
  $dbh->rollback();
}else{
  $dbh->commit();
}
$session->flush();
```

When an sql error is occured, an eval block catches exception and rollback transaction.
After that, CGI::Session does not retrieve session object no more.

Because prepare_cached statement failes at CGI::Session::DBI.pm.
CGI::Session::DBI.pm use prepare_cached($sql,undef,3). '3' is safest way of using cached statement, but it never find broken statement at this situation.

How to fix this ?
raise request to change CGI::Session::DBI.pm to use prepare() statement ?
write store(),retrieve(),traverse() function in firebird.pm to use prepare() statement ?

It may other prepare_cached() going to fail after catch exception...

---

1) I add die statement on CGI::Session->errstr()
 I got an error "new(): failed: load(): couldn't retrieve data: retrieve(): $sth->execute failed with error message"
2) I flush session object after session->load()
 if $session is valid, changes are stored to DB.
3) I replace begin_work() to {AutoCommit}=0
 results are same. I can use $dbh normally after catching exception and rollback, BUT new CGI::Session returns error. 
------------------------------------------ added 2017/07/26 18:47 JST

Please give me your suggestion.

Thank you.

Comment: maybe `session->flush` kills session? maybe one is expected to remove any value from `$sessid` ?

Comment: $session->flush() does not raise any exceptions.
After $session->flush(), another query works well, but next "new CGI::Session()" returns empty. CGI::Session->load() returns undef.

Comment: I also tested it by removing $session->flush(), but next CGI:Session returned empty.

Comment: Why are you calling `new CGI::Session()` again? Do you need to retrieve different sessions in the same script? ... `$session->flush()` does not raise exceptions unless you tell it so, you could add `$session->flush() or die "Unable to update session storage!"` and see if that raises an exception

Comment: Sample code does not raise error standalone.
This is in the web system, connect() statement is in the common package and pooling connection.
So, each web screen(cgi program) call new CGI::Session() at start and retrieve $session and process with it.
My trouble is "retrieve fails at all screen after sql error occurs in some screen".

Answer (score 2):

There are various things you could try before request changes to CGI::Session::Driver::DBI.pm ...

First, change the way `new CGI::Session` is called in order to diagnose if the problem happens when the session is created or loaded:

```
my $session = CGI::Session->new('dbi:firebird',$sessid,{Handle=>$dbh}) or die CGI::Session->errstr();
```

The methods `param` or `delete` stores changes to the session inside `$session` handle, not in DB. `flush` stores in DB the changes made inside the session handle. Use `$session->flush()` only after a session->param set/update or a session delete:

```
$session->param('p1','someParamValue');
$session->flush() or die 'Unable to update session storage!';

# OR
$session->delete();
$session->flush() or die 'Unable to update session storage!';
```

The method `flush` does not destroy `$session` handle (you still can call `$session->param('p1')` after the flush). In some cases mod_perl caches `$session` causing problems to the next attempt to load that same session. In those cases it needs to be destroyed when it's not needed anymore:

```
undef($session)
```

The last thing i can suggest is avoid using `begin_work` method, control the transaction behavior with `AutoCommit` instead (because the [DBD::Firebird documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-Firebird/Firebird.pm#TRANSACTION_SUPPORT) says that's the way transactions should be controlled) and `commit` inside the eval block:

```
eval {
    # Setting AutoCommit to 0 enables transaction behavior
    $dbh->{AutoCommit} = 0;

    my $sql = "SELECT * FROM SAMPLETABLE"
    my $st = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $st->execute();

    while (my $R = $st->fetchrow_hashref()) {
        ...
        }

    $st->finish();
    $dbh->commit();
    };
if ($@) {
     warn "Tansaction aborted! $@";
     $dbh->rollback();
     }

# Remember to set AutoCommit to 1 after the eval
$dbh->{AutoCommit} = 1;
```

You said you wrote your own session driver for Firebird... You should see how the CGI/Driver/sqlite.pm or CGI/Driver/mysql.pm are made, maybe you need to write some fetching method you are missing...

Hope this helps!!

Comment: 1) add die CGI::Session->errstr():
  new(): failed: load(): couldn't retrieve data: retrieve(): $sth->execute failed with error message
2) flushing session object:
 if $session is valid, changes are stored to DB.
3) use {AutoCommit}=0 and others:
 situation is same. I can use $dbh normally after catching exception and rollback, BUT new CGI::Session returns error.
---
My Driver/firebird.pm has only init() and table_name(), then use store/retrieve in DBI.pm. I wrote firebird.pm to load DBD::Firebird and make DSN as 'dbi:firebird'.

Comment: I add store,retrieve,traverse without "_cached" to firebird.pm. It looks working fine.
mysql.pm has mk_dsn,init,table_name,store. store() is changed to use 'ON DUPLICATES' from DBI.pm.
DBI->begin_work() changes {AutoCommit} to 0.
I found workarounds. So, I want to know why cached statements are gone?

Comment: Could you update your question with the errors you have found?